# How can I get heads-up notifications for WhatsApp?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, 5.0-lollipop

I really love the new heads-up notifications in Lollipop because they look much cleaner now, but it's really weird some apps use them or not.

I would really want them to work with WhatsApp, but I just don't find out how, or if it is possible.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: WhatsApp has implemented heads-up notification natively. However, users can still use the apps listed here to display heads-up notification for other apps. If the user is already using it, don't forget to disable WhatsApp's entry to prevent double heads-up notification.

---

At that time, it's impossible to do this directly from WhatsApp official app.

The [heads-up notification](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) is only shown when the notification is set to high-priority, max-priority, or full-screen notification by the developer. So, the "official" answer was to wait for them integrate the function.

However, there are 3rd-party apps that implement this feature for all apps:

1. [Heads-up notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=codes.simen.l50notifications)
2. [Heads Up! - notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodblockwithoutco.headsup)

You can control which apps are permitted to show the heads-up notification (I recommend you to do that before they flood the screen), and the customization is also pretty extensive.