# Why are heads up notifications not showing after an update in Samsung Galaxy E7?

Tags: notifications, samsung, 5.1-lollipop

I've recently updated my Samsung device to Android 5.1.1 lollipop and as I have been playing around with it I noticed that I wasn't getting any heads up notifications. Is there a certain option to turn it on or I just don't have it?

Comment: Have you checked if it is switched on in Settings > Notifications > Heads up?

Comment: See that's just it I don't have such a option like that in my settings...

Comment: Is there a search function in your settings? What device do you have specifically?

Comment: I have a search function but I when I search "heads up" It doesn't show anything. I have a Samsung Galaxy E7

Comment: AFAIK, there's no system option to turn-off heads up, unless you turn off the whole notification (but doesn't seem your case, since you still received normal notification?). Otherwise, check the system notification on Settings - Notifications - App Notifications (or similar).

Comment: Could it be that Samsung disabled the heads up functionality in the ROM?

Comment: Probably related: [How can I get heads-up notification for <insert app name> on Lollipop?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/89342/44325). I think you updated from KitKat directly to Lollipop 5.1.1? If that's the case, then FYI not all apps show heads-up. It depends if the app developers implement it or not.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings>sound and notification > notification on lock screen>show content hope it work for you

Comment: Notification on lock screen =/= heads-up notification. The former is only shown on the lock screen, the latter may be shown anytime, popping from the top of the screen.