# How to enable the "Allow Peeking" option on Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications

I have recently upgraded my Samsung Galaxy N3 (SM-N9005) to Android 5.0 in the hope that I would get the heads-up style notifications. According to online resources I have found, this option is called "Allow Peeking" and is found under the notification options for each app.

However, when I go into the notifications for the apps I have installed, none of them have the "Allow Peeking" option.

Is there something else I need to enable? If not, how do I get the "Allow Peeking" to appear?

Comment: On my Galaxy S4, currently running Lollipop as pushed by Verizon, there was a single setting for "hide content in lock screen notifications" or something very similar, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Related: [How can I get heads-up notification for <insert app name> on Lollipop?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/89342/44325)

Answer (score 2):

"Heads-Up" Notification is introduced in Android Lollipop. However you can only disable the feature by updating to Marshmallow. Marshmallow has the option for disabling Heads-Up notification so-called "Allow Peeking".

Below is the screenshots for Lollipop and Marshmallow.

[image]

<sup>App notifications on Lollipop</sup>

[image]

<sup>App notifications on Marshmallow</sup>