# Sony Xperia Z5 not showing Heads up Notifications on Marshmallow

Tags: notifications, sony-xperia, toast-notifications, sony-xperia-z5

I've recently bought a Sony Xperia Z5, and can't get the Heads up Notifications to work on any app at all.

I have gone into the app settings and selected "Sounds & Notifications / App Notifications / (app name) / Allow peeking", but there are no heads up notifications from any of the installed apps. Is there another hidden setting somewhere that I need to enable in order to get this working? I really don't want to download another app if this should be working as standard.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: It... doesn't really work like that. By default, only developer of the apps can use either heads-up or normal notification, and user cannot change that behaviour... unless you're okay with 3rd-party apps (see [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89342/how-can-i-get-heads-up-notifications-for-whatsapp))

Comment: Hi Andrew - thanks. I've seen screenshots of this in action on a Z5, though. GMail does it, but not on my phone. Are you saying that Outlook, etc. also don't do it?

Comment: AFAIK, Yahoo! Mail, Outlook, Inbox by Google don't do it. Messaging (Google's SMS app) does it, but I couldn't remember others. Not sure about Gmail though, since I'm not using it.

Comment: I'm really disappointed with this - I hate having to "download an app" to get a basic feature working, as 9 times out of 10 they either look rubbish or are filled with ads. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Any app installed that is using notification access?[image]

Comment: How do I get to this - is it in the "Settings / Apps / " area somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

do you have any antivirus or cleaner apps installed on your device? I had very same problem with notifications after upgrading to marshmallow. It appears "360 security" blocked all the notifications automatically (except Facebook and Gmail) after upgrading android. So long story short check your cleaner and antivirus application settings for notifications. It helped me, I have all my notifications back, woohoo! :-D